# Activating automatic spell checking on input fields in Opera

Tags: opera, spell-check

How do I activate spell checking on input text fields by default in Opera? Spelling is checked automatically for text areas but for single-line input fields it only appears as an option in the context menu.

I am an ex-user of Firefox that has recently migrated to Opera Next (12.00 beta 64-bit Linux edition) and would like to make this available.

Is there a configuration option, or perhaps an add-on, that will enable single-line spell checking on all pages by default?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/intro/speed/#spell:

> For single line text fields, spell checking is not automatic, but you
>   can enable it by right-clicking the field and checking *Check
>   spelling* in the context menu.

If you want to spellcheck single-line textboxes, you could set the `spellcheck` attribute to true.

I have created a user JS that enforces the `spellcheck` attribute to true automatically.

Enable spellcheck:

https://gist.github.com/3154440/

Installing user JS:

1. Create a folder for storing user JS files.
2. Go to the user JS on GitHub > Right click on "raw" > Save Linked Content As... > Save the JS file to your user JS folder.
3. Opera > Settings > Preferences... > Advanced > Content > JavaScript Options... > Under "User JavaScript folder", select "Choose..." > Select the folder > OK > OK > OK.

Comment: This does indeed enforce the spell check attribute. However, spell checking is still not enabled by default due to the resetting of what dictionary to use. I thank you for your effort, though. I thought this would work.